# SAML/SSO for magento admin and module application?

Tags: admin, login

I created a module for my admin panel that requires me to login to Magento's admin panel, click the menu link to my module, then login to my module application, which is external.

I would like a solution to auto login and logout the admin user to magento and my application, instead of having to login to each separately.

I think it also poses a security risk, since my module application doesn't logout the user signed in when they log out of Magento. So if someone else logs in with the same computer, the application would already have the previous user logged in. Which means the new user can see the previous users information within that module.

Please advise me on a way to solve this problem, to create a single login situation. the current application already offers SSO. I've never used SSO before so i'm clueless to what to do and where to start, so please be detailed with your answers.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

If Magento admin users gonna be your main authentication source and you want to SSO between your app and Magento you need to:

1. Deploy an Identity Provider using simpleSAMLphp [1], it will use Magento admin user database as authentication authsource [2]
2. Add SAML support to magento admin section. [3] and connect it with the Identity Provider
3. Add SAML support to your app and connect it with the Identity Provider. For that you can use OneLogin's open source SAML toolkits [4]

[1] https://simplesamlphp.org

[2] https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/sqlauth:sql

[3] https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/31527/s/admin-saml-single-sign-on-plugin/category/12825/

[4] https://www.onelogin.com/resources/saml-toolkits

Comment: I get the gist of what you're saying, but beyond that i'm oblivious. Could you provide a tutorial to do this or connect with me when you have time to help me work on it?

Comment: In each link you will find enough documentation in order to learn, but it will require time and some effort. If you get blocked with something you always can expose your doubts here or at the simpleSAMLphp mail list.
If you are looking for professional support:
https://simplesamlphp.org/support